# RunDeck can it be used in an Airgap environment

Tags: rundeck

I have an Airgap environment and would like to know if it will work without internet access. The systems I have can't reach the outside of the enclave.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your Environment? Rundeck doesn't need internet access, you can deploy it in a server on your local network and dispatch commands and jobs to your "LAN" remote nodes.

Comment: Thanks, I have an isolated private network with no internet access and that has caused me some issues with other products. I have started looking at RunDeck and have it up in a regular lab and so far, I like it much better the AWX.

Answer (score 0):

Rundeck doesn't need internet access, you can deploy a Rundeck instance in a server on your local network and dispatch commands and jobs to your "LAN" remote nodes.